# The conditions is not executing correctly

Tags: c

For `age` >= 25 and a Unmarried Female the Output is not correct.

> /* A company insures its drivers if either of the following conditions
>   are satisfied
>         Driver is married.
>         Driver is an unmarried, male and above 30 years of age.
>         Driver is unmarried, female and above 25 years of age.
>         Write a program to decide if a driver is to be insured using logical operators. */
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main()
> {
>   char name[100]; 
>   char ms, gender;
>   int age;
>
>   printf("\n\tNAME: ");
>   scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name);
>
>   printf("\n\tAGE: ");
>   scanf("%d", &age);
>
>   printf("\n\tMARRIED [Y/N]: ");
>   scanf("%s",&ms);
>
>   printf("\n\tGENDER [M/F]: ");
>   scanf("%s",&gender);
>
>   if(ms == 'Y'|| ms == 'y')//married
>       printf("\n\t1. INSURED\n");
>
>   else//unmarried
>   {
>       if(gender == 'M' || gender == 'm')//male
>       {
>           if(age >= 30)
>               printf("\n\t2. INSURED\n");
>           else
>               printf("\n\t3. NOT INSURED\n");
>       }
>       else//female
>       {
>           if(age >= 25)
>               printf("\n\t4. INSURED\n");     
>           else
>               printf("\n\t5. NOT INSURED\n");  
>       }
>   }
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Kindly help me find the mistake. To locate the mistake I have numbered the output to know. Where the fault is. But I am not able to find any.
the output:

```
NAME: 

AGE: 26

MARRIED [Y/N]: n

GENDER [M/F]: f

5. NOT INSURED
```

Comment: Fix-my-code requests are off topic. Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....). **Use the debugger** `gdb` (to run your program step by step and query its state) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Read [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Sorry! I am not sure what you meant by "gcc -Wall -Wextra -g".

Comment: GCC is a free software compiler (and the usual one on Linux distribution). I recommend using it (and I also recommend installing and using some Linux distribution if you are learning C programming). You should spend a few days reading documentation of your compiler and your debugger.

Comment: I know about that. But, what is gdb and how am i to use it.

Comment: GIYF. See [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and read its [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html). Both `gcc` and  `gdb` are command line tools, and you will use them in some terminal

Comment: @rgo - have you heard of google? Its surprisingly good at answering trivial questions...

Comment: @enhzflep Oh! I have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables `ms` and `gender` are single characters and not character arrays storing a string.

You are reading into `ms` with `%s` format specifier.
Use `%c` format specifier instead which the one for reading into a `char`.

Like

```
scanf(" %c",&ms);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%s",&ms);
```

The space before the `%c` is to ignore the white spaces that may remain in the input buffer which would other have been read into `ms` instead of the real input.

Comment: BTW, any good compiler with all warnings enabled would have detected this mistake, hence my advice for `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did compile as you said: gcc -Wall -Wextra -g [filename].c and I didn't get any error message.

Comment: I'm sure you got some warnings (in the terminal where you run that `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g filename.c -o progname` command). BTW, you might avoid [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) and compile with a command line in some terminal

Comment: I didn't. There were no warnings or any message. I am using the terminal on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Ok. But did you use `gdb` ?

Comment: @J...S When I compiled with "%s" as you asked. I was not able to input any data for the married and gender column. It went straight to infer 'Not Insured' I did use 26 as age.

Sorry type error. I meant %c

Comment: @rgo Don't compile with `%s`. Use ` %c` for both `ms` and `gender`. Notice the space before `%c`.

Comment: @J...S When I used "% c" with a space I got message:   unknown conversion type character 0x20 in format [-Wformat=]
  scanf("% c",&ms);

Comment: @rgo Space before the whole `%c`. Not between the % and c.

Comment: @J...S If you can Kindly check with this data: Age 26, Married: N, Gender: F. It suppose to output '4.Insured' but it prints out '5.Not Insured'

Comment: @rgo See [demo](https://ideone.com/f7C66U).

Comment: @J...S Thank you! Kindly explain, why the space  in "  %c" is required.

Comment: @rgo After reading into `age`, you press enter for `\n` or some white space, right? That won't be consumed by the `scanf()` reading `age` and would remain in the input buffer. This would be read by the next `scanf()` and seeing the `\n` it thinks the input for `ms` is over and goes to the next line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155687/discussion-between-rgo-and-j-s).

Answer (score 2):

You declare `ms` and `gender` as `char variable` and you use format specifier of a `char array`.

So, you replace your `scanf` statement from any statement written below for `ms` and `gender` input.

```
 1. scanf("\n%c",&ms);

 2. scanf("\t%c",&ms);

 3. scanf("\r%c",&ms);

 4. scanf(" %c",&ms);
```

Similarly replace `scanf` statement for gender also.

Comment: Notice that every space-like character `\n` `\t` `\r` and the space `' '` itself behave identically for `scanf` control string; so always using a space makes IMHO more readable code